# Access list element in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am getting this list from server(php):

```
["Ak-Bulak","Balykchy","Batken"]
```

how can i access it and put into selects options thru js, what i tried is:

```
for (var i in data) {
   $('#cities').append('<option>'+ data[i] +'</option>');
}
```

it putting every chars as one option: `<option>[</option>`, `<option>"</option>`...

how can i access each element here? not each char..

Comment: How are you getting this list?  is it a php var on your php page?

Comment: Please don't use [`for .. in`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a list, you have a string. So first, parse that string:

```
var list = JSON.parse('["Ak-Bulak","Balykchy","Batken"]')
```

And then, loop over it as you already did, or without using keys:

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    $('#cities').append('<option>'+ data[i] +'</option>');
}
```

Comment: If the assumption that the user is dealing JSON is correct (and I figure it is), this is the proper answer. If you need to support a browser which does not natively support the JSON API, you can download `json2.js` from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and load it on your page before the code which needs to parse JSON.

Comment: Seems he is using jQuery so he can use `jQuery.parseJSON` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: remember to use `console.log` when strange things like this happen. You can use `console.log` with objects, and inspect them with firebug/dev tools (F12).

Answer (score 3):

If it's a var on your php page something like this would work

```
for (var i in <?php echo '["Ak-Bulak","Balykchy","Batken"]'; ?>) {
   $('#cities').append('<option>'+ i +'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse this string as JSON first.

```
var buffer = eval(data)
for (var i in buffer) {
    $('#cities').append('<option>'+ buffer[i] +'</option>');
}
```

But if you use eval() you must be sure that input data is consistent.
updated.

Comment: Even better to use [parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). `var buffer = $.parseJson(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    var data='["Ak-Bulak","Balykchy","Batken"]';
    data=JSON.parse(data);


for (var i in data) {
   $('#cities').append('<option>'+ data[i] +'</option>');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var data=<?php echo '["Ak-Bulak","Balykchy","Batken"]'; ?>;

for (var i in data) {
   $('#cities').append('<option>'+ data[i] +'</option>');
}
```